# Store in mysql database de the User_ID of Facebook

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, oauth

I am getting problems trying to get the Facebook User_ID and storing in a mysql database.
I have two files, one with the Appid, secret,... and with the Oauth for the user, and then I have and index2.php redirected from the dialog of the Oauth with the mysql database.
With functions do you you, or you will use to take the user id and strong in my mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

When they go through the Oauth Dialogue how are you getting the data it passes back? If its being passed back in using a POST then everything is stored in $_POST structure and you just need to pull it out.